# Why type is being set to unknown on optional field in particular setup with generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I was trying to fix some types regarding DataTable on carbon-components-react, but got stuck at making one property optional. I got to the point where I created my own demo to show this problem:

```
import React from "react";

interface Human {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address?: string;
}

interface ButtonProps<R extends Human> {
  name: R["name"];
  age: R["age"];
  address?: R["address"];
  onClick?: Function;
}

interface RenderProps<R extends Human> {
  human: R;
  getButtonProps(data?: ButtonProps<R>): ButtonProps<R>;
}

export interface DataTableProps<R extends Human> {
  rows: R[];
  render(props: RenderProps<R>): React.ReactNode;
}

class DataTable<R extends Human> extends React.Component<DataTableProps<R>> {
  render() {
    return this.props.rows.map((h) => {
      const buttonProps: () => Human = () => ({ ...h }); // This is only to be able to see the type of buttonProps in IDE

      return this.props.render({ human: h, getButtonProps: buttonProps });
    });
  }
}

interface TableButtonProps {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
}

const TableButton = (props: TableButtonProps) => (
  <button>Button for {props.name}</button>
);

export const Demo = () => {
  // This works
  const man1: Human = {
    name: "Anna",
    age: 30,
  };

  // This seems to be ok since "address" is optional
  // but this isn't working!
  const man2 = {
    name: "Tom",
    age: 32,
  };

  // This works
  const man3 = {
    name: "John",
    age: 40,
    address: "404 Street Unknown",
  };

  return (
    <DataTable
      rows={[man2]}
      render={({ getButtonProps }) => {
        return <TableButton {...getButtonProps()} />;
      }}
    ></DataTable>
  );
};
```

The error I am getting at TableButton:

```
Type '{ name: string; age: number; address?: unknown; onClick?: Function | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'TableButtonProps'.
  Types of property 'address' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322
```

The `address` property has `unknown` type for some reason. When I use syntax like `man1` or `man3` everything is working, you can replace it at `rows=`. Why is `man2` not working even though the type is still set to extend Human? Is TypeScript getting lost?

You can test this by initializing project using `npx create-react-app mydemo --template=typescript`

// Edit:

```
interface ButtonProps<R extends Human> {
  name: Human["name"];
  age: Human["age"];
  address?: Human["address"];
  onClick?: Function;
}
```

Also seems to be fixing this issue and "protect" `address` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have noticed that the problem is in `address` property.

For some reason it is infered as `unknown`.

Usually, you are getting `unknown` because TS is unable to infer generic parameter.

See example:

```js
const foo = <T,>(arg: T): T => arg

// const foo: <unknown>(arg: unknown) => unknown
const result = foo() // unknown
```

Consider this example:

```js
type GetAddress<T extends Human> = T extends Human ? T['address'] : never

type Result = GetAddress<{ name: 'John', age: 42 }> // unknown
```

Technically, `{ name: 'John', age: 42 }` is assignable to `Human` because `address` is optional. From the other hand, `T['address']` can't return `undefined` because it is not javascript - it is (Sparta) typesystem of typescript. Hence, if TS is unable to get/infer `address` property, the most safest option would be return an `unknown`;

Let's go back to your example.

For the sake of readability I have replaced built in react component with custom `Component` class:

```js
import React from "react";

interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address?: string;
}

interface ButtonProps<R extends Human> {
    name: R["name"];
    age: R["age"];
    address?: R["address"];
    onClick?: Function;
}

interface RenderProps<R extends Human> {
    human: R;
    getButtonProps(data?: ButtonProps<R>): ButtonProps<R>;
}


export interface DataTableProps<R extends Human, Address extends Human['address']> {
    rows: R[];
    render: (props: RenderProps<R>) => React.ReactNode;
}

class Component<Props>{
    constructor(public props: Props) {
        this.props = props
    }
}

class Foo<T extends Human> extends Component<DataTableProps<T, T['address']>>{
    render = () => {
        return this.props.rows.map(
            (row) =>
                this
                    .props
                    .render(
                        { human: row, getButtonProps: () => ({ ...row }) }
                    )
        );
    }
}

const human = { age: 42, name: 'John Doe' }

const jsx = new Foo({
    rows: [human],
    render: ({ getButtonProps }) => {
        const x = getButtonProps().address
        return <TableButton {...getButtonProps()} />;
    }
})
```

Please take a loot at this line `Component<DataTableProps<T, T['address']>>`

I have purposely added `T['address']` to show you how TS will infer it.
[image]

As you see - it is unknown. So, we ended up with object `{age: number, name: string, address: unknown}` which is not assignable to `Human` because of `address`.

You may ask:

**Wait, but why it works with explicit type?**

`const human: Human = { age: 42, name: 'John Doe' }`

This is because without explicit type, `R` is infered as `{age: number, name: string}` whereas with explicit `Human` type it is infered as `{age:number, name: string, address?:string, onClick?:Function}`.

Hence, if you want to fix your error, you just need to provide explicit generic parameter for `DataTable` class.

See example:

```js
    <DataTable<Human> // <---------------- fix is here
      rows={[man2]}
      render={({ getButtonProps }) => {
        return <TableButton {...getButtonProps()} />;
      }}
    ></DataTable>
```

Btw, very interesting question.

**UPDATE**
You can also use this helper:

```js
/**
 * Replace all unknown props with appropriate Human props
 */
type HandleProps<T extends Human> = T & Omit<Human, keyof T>

// ............

class DataTable<R extends Human> extends React.Component<DataTableProps<HandleProps<R>>> {
    render() {
        return this.props.rows.map((h) => {
            const buttonProps: () => Human = () => ({ ...h });

            return this.props.render({ human: h, getButtonProps: buttonProps });
        });
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgAkBXEFauAb3LgFxqKEEgBccAM4woNAOYVBcFHPFCOAI3qLBKACZ6ikyQH4J02dQXkAvpRp0GTOACE2MGBGoAFHGEkAPAhwSAAedNR6kqwcXAB8vPyCwqISCADa%20ClI%20AC6OgIqahn4RXkFygZGpmmZ%20oZIxuVJAl4AwgA2wGgA1mZwAGJs1BjAXhR25AD0AFQz-DOISGAdzigdHXDDPdQQAO7cYH7Re8AwABbKYEcQR8AodDGch8cLU%20QwAJ5gzCxceh0kL5boEACohcJISLRdjPBIAXjg4IAZHAAPIgM4BWFcAA0cB6SE%20EEwSLilCotHojDQzGQkXowP8QQhESiT3iiSU51i1DSFVUMDcHi8TMkAAo9A8UP1hZ4fMcgnEAJQSOWixUIOITShhSCwOAOanOAAi0tBKA0gLFLLCbJhvISfCUOD2klq%20RacCIDKg4pu-jSUL0jM1KqD6BgADpkJGAHIQEM68hoVbGOBmmAoC1WpC2yHQjnUBJ24PRWMYKNtXCQahQmABTPZy3WxV-SKtkFKuJOr0%20kN%205VcpSCIgwNhQbgXYCSKMB2eu2ecMDi8XnIfw3sj7dwNBeaRwDTueViiTijcJHHcRHnuCbuDinhwKMvy42ZUUL0771IceTuDTrO85Rv29CPnAPLPBI5z4oK6oKiCEhHiKCH%20HA74VEoGFenYkxGk4tJIi2SDwWKw4CNk5gyPIFT1NU-QWDRtiUHu1AHjmgLwXeD7zhIHEkceGogheD5egEyHynEXGYNAvDAdkNgBFMEleOSH66qE%20rwKxB4mkgIAQNxt73s6ghTFMSLnDOcB7NAPSSF6OnwM8ACMEhXtxpnbpRBAAILUMI%20C4l%20uiqBIADMAAMwVYZ%20SjmZZ1mSEg%20nRJ4h7MBAPRSDQhGlFUjSSPghrRLcMBjMIHReglyEAVZ0QztQADk8C2VAPTyAAhI5%207OVwABMnkhRRIhqPgoK4EFw3KGFcDhf1MWCDYcVmRZoL1TZdkOUoTlwM84VDd%20Pn4AAUhA5zUFN35FBIAAs0XTXRhUSPg923XAADKMgpfAACq1A7Psl2LQIy2UC6v4Ttw4rTY25rEdNLr7JI8I8Okzz9bkdjfhDvqo%20BcGCah0TvneW449uY5Q3AAT8VxPAvlGhMoWK542HAUzaojS3YzucRKU2-Hkko6lg5QQA)

It will replace all `unknown` props with appropriate `Human` props

Comment: Kind of disappointed that there isn't really a real fix for that, but thanks for explanation! This also explains why using Human to infer type is also fixing it.